# mysql load data scripts - save the output

Tags: mysql

When running a mysql load data command from the console their is output that tells you the number of records loaded and the time.  Here is an example:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/RESPONSE.txt' replace INTO TABLE db1.RESPONSE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
-> ignore 2 lines;
Query OK, 3088090 rows affected, 65535 warnings (2 min 40.14 sec)
Records: 3088090  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 661200
```

I have many tables that I load data into each day and I wanted to create a script to do it and then review the output.  The issue that I run into is that when I load the data using a script like this:

```
mysql <loadscript > loadresults
```

The file load results is always empty.

Is there anyway to capture the same output that you would get on the console in a file?

Comment: you mean redirecting the stdout into some file ....that can be done by redirecting the standard-output into a file using >>  ...... ex: do something >> savehere.txt

Comment: Trying adding 2>&1 to capture the stderr as well.  mysql <loadscript > loadresults 2>&1

Comment: >> produced the same (empty) results as >  I am going to try 2>&1 tomorrow.

Comment: mysql <loadscript > loadresults and mysql <loadscript >> load results.txt 2>&1 produced the same results, both empty files.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem as the original question, and ([this post](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/05/capturing-errors-and-warnings-from-load-data-infile/)) hints a solution: use "-vv" option to enable the double verbose of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying problem in Windows. The only solution I could find was to use mysqlimport as follows:

```
mysqlimport -p  --fields-terminated-by="," --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" ^
--fields-optionally-enclosed-by="""" --local ^   
myDatabase myTable.txt
```